# Adding tokens when matching a vector to multiple strings using sapply and grepl

Tags: regex, r, sapply, grepl

I am trying to check for matches between a vector containing many elements and a column of a data frame which contains a string.

```
vec <- c("KIND", "Quest")

string <- ("lieberkind", "kind", "KIND", "Quest Nutrition", "Quest")

x <- sapply(vec, function (x) grepl(x, string, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

This is the result:

```
> x
      KIND Quest
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE
```

The problem is in the first result for "KIND" which ends up producing a TRUE value for 'lieberkind'.

Normally, I would have just added a token to specify word boundary like:

```
grepl("\\bKIND\\b", string, ignore.case = TRUE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But I don't know how I can do that when I am using the `sapply` to compare each element of vector against each element of the string.

I cannot do this obviously:

```
x <- sapply(vec, function (x) grepl(\\bx\\b, string, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe `paste0("\\b",x,"\\b")` instead of `\\bx\\b`? Are all your entries alphanumeric?

Comment: `sprintf("\\b%s\\b", vec)`

Comment: yes, all entries are alphanumeric!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to check word boundaries, they depend on your data. If you need to use word boundaries, use

```
x <- sapply(vec, function (x) grepl(paste0("\\b",x,"\\b"), string, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

or as [Jota's recommended equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591555/adding-tokens-when-matching-a-vector-to-multiple-strings-using-sapply-and-grepl/38591890#comment64571510_38591555):

```
x <- sapply(vec, function (x) grepl(sprintf("\\b%s\\b", x), string, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

However, if your `vec` contains entries with special characters inside (note: not at the start or end), then you will need to escape them with something like

```
x <- sapply(vec, function (x) grepl(paste0("\\b",gsub("([][/\\\\^$*+?.()|{}-])", "\\\\\\1", x),"\\b"), string, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

And finally, if you define the word boundary as a whitespace char or start/end of string, I'd rather recommend a PCRE regex like

```
x <- sapply(vec, function (x) grepl(paste0("(?<!\\S)",gsub("([][/\\\\^$*+?.()|{}-])", "\\\\\\1", x),"(?!\\S)"), string, ignore.case = TRUE, perl=TRUE))
```

The result in all the 3 cases with your test data will look like:

```
      KIND Quest
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE
```

P.S. Whether you use `paste0` or `sprintf`, you will get the same results.